# Code with Extracting Thumbnail from video is not working in a node

Tags: 7

PHP script when run from linux shell is working fine. But when the same code is put in a node its not displaying anything.

Below is the code:

```
<?php

 /*$videopath=$_GET['videoname'];
   $imagepath=$_GET['imagedestination'];*/

   if(file_exists('/opt/lampp/htdocs/mydashboard/guitar_file.avi'))
      {
       print 'entered';
       $path_ffmpeg = '/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg ';
       $offset = '-itsoffset -4  -i ';
       $video_file_location = '/opt/lampp/htdocs/mydashboard/guitar_file.avi';
       $add_params = ' -vcodec mjpeg -vframes 1 -an -f rawvideo -s 320x240 ';
       $thumnail_filename = '/opt/lampp/htdocs/mydashboard/test_thumbnail.jpg';
       try
         {
          $command='/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -itsoffset -4  -i /opt/lampp/htdocs/mydashboard/guitar_file.avi -vcodec mjpeg -vframes 1 -an -f rawvideo -s 320x240 /opt/lampp/htdocs/mydashboard/test123sdasd.jpg';
          $return_value = exec($command, $output);

 ?>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are there any errors in drupal logs or in server logs?
I think problem can be in the path to files.

Comment: I found this error in Server Logs: /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg: /opt/lampp/lib/libgcc_s.so.1: version `GCC_4.2.0' not found (required by /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6). How can i resolve this issue.

Comment: You have some syntax errors in that snippet.

Comment: Renaming /opt/lampp/lib/libgcc_s.so to /opt/lampp/lib/libgcc_s.so.1 solved my issue.
Thanks for your help